# Does the Joker consider any act of violence to be too wrong?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker

The Joker is a psychopath, apparently fine with murdering just about anyone in any way.

However, according to [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/EvenEvilHasStandards/ComicBooks), some versions of him do have some standards. For example, he wouldn't work with Nazis or do things he considers just plain "mean."

Based on this information, has the Joker ever stated or implied that any act of violence would be too wrong or extreme, even for him?

Answer (score 10):

Depends on your definition of Canon. I don't remember the exact issue, but there was a Batman/Captain America crossover back in, oh, the 80s or so. Joker ends up teaming up with Red Skull . Cap and Batman chase the two villains to an airfield where they can simply watch as the bad guys plane flies away.

On the plane, Red Skull reveals to Joker his plans to drop a nuke on the USA. That wasn't what Joker had signed up for. Joker ends up betraying Red Skull by forcing the bomb to go off prematurely, killing them both. As he does so, Red Skull yells something like "what do you think you're doing?" And Joker replies "I may be a homicidal maniac, but I'm an AMERICAN homicidal maniac!"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, it's likely that the Joker isn't into genocide because he enjoys hurting people, and genocide empties out the victim pool.  It's kind of a conservation issue.

Comment: I can't quite read the comic. Does the Joker not approve of the plan because it involves killing so many people, or solely because Red Skull is a Nazi?

Comment: @RogueJedi the latter.

Comment: @RogueJedi the latter it seems

Answer (score -3):

In *Batman* 428 (January 1989), The Joker beats Jason Todd (the 2nd Robin) to death with a crowbar

[image]

and then proceeded to blow up the building he was in.

[image]

In the graphic novel *The Killing Joke*, the Joker terrorizes Commissioner Gordon by shooting his daughter Barbara
[image]

(and possibly raping her, or at the very least beating her naked body and taking pictures to show to Jim).

***In my opinion***, those two actions are "just plain mean".

Comment: "and taking pictures to show Gordon" assuming you mean Jim Gordon, her father, isn't that him sitting right there when she's shot? So why would the Joker need pictures to show him? Or did he abscond with the body and do that elsewhere?

Comment: I don't recall, it's been a long time.  I believe Joker takes both Gordon and Barbara.  The pictures are of her naked and being tortured, not being shot. http://images-cdn.moviepilot.com/images/c_fill,h_1023,w_655/t_mp_quality/iwoh2fpaummmxd1buj5g/batman-the-killing-joke-did-the-joker-really-rape-barbara-gordon-image-from-the-comic-542861.jpg

Comment: The question seems to be looking for things that he wouldn't do. What you've provided are things that he's done.

Comment: Oooohhhh, good point.  I misread the end of the question.

Comment: @TylerH You should read The Killing Joke, it's a good read. But if you prefer spoilers: ˙ǝɹǝɥʇ sǝɹnʇɔıd ǝɥʇ ɯıɥ sʍoɥs pɐɯ ǝuoʎuɐ uɹnʇ uɐɔ ʎɐp pɐq ǝʃƃuıs ɐ ʇɐɥʇ ʇuıod sıɥ ǝʌoɹd oʇ ʇdɯǝʇʇɐ uɐ uı puɐ ʞɹɐd ʇuǝɯǝsnɯɐ pǝuopuɐqɐ uɐ oʇ uopɹo⅁ sǝɯɐſ sǝʞɐʇ ɹǝʞoſ

Comment: @Zommuter I have read it and seen the animated movie already since posting that comment in February, thanks!